# Logical Pattern

Tags: pattern, visual

Been staring at this question for 20 minutes and can't come to a reasonable answer, any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Is it ethically right to help? It might be an ongoing contest or something similar?

Comment: @ABcDexter It says "practice", so I don't think it could be an ongoing contest.

Comment: @ABcDexter it is a practice question for graduate psychometric tests, anyone can access these questions, they are just to demonstrate the type of question you can be asked and the format the question will be in.

Comment: Ok, understood :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Had some real trouble with this logical sequence today](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72413/had-some-real-trouble-with-this-logical-sequence-today)

Answer (score 4):

This fits:

> >>

because:

> Each row and column contain a 2-word and 2 4-words, of which one has two of each symbol and one has three of one symbol and one of the other. Also in each row the 2-word is NOT the first letter of the first 4-word, and NOT the first letter of the second 4-word (NOT is used in the logical sense). In each column, the 2-word appears in the middle of each 4-word with the 3:1 ratio.

Comment: That's pretty convincing. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here it goes:

> " " < > " " is the answer

Because

> The right one has each option in the rows. The three options are " " ">" and "<"
>  So you know it's _ _ _ " "

Part 2

> The left one has each option in the columns. 
>  So you know it's " " _ _ " "

Part 3

> In each of the columns the middle 2 share 2 alike and since top and bottom are the same you can rule out " " >> " "
>  For one of the 2 middle columns on each column you share 3 like symbols so at least one of the 2 in the middle are ">". So you have either >< or <>
>  In column one the shared column is column 3, in column 2 the shared is 2 so it must go back to 3 in the 3rd column so you have " " _ > " "
>  The second spot must be < because it can't be ">" but there's a second reason. In the column that doesn't share like symbols. 2 are the same and the other is different since both point right this one must point left.

Therefore:

> " " < > " " is your answer

A second answer fits though:

> " " > < " "

Because:

> In the first column the 2 character item is in row 1 so it takes chars 3 and 4 from row 3

Also

> In the second column the 2 character item is in row 3 so it takes chars 3 and 4 from row 1

Therefore:

> In the third column it's in row 2 and takes from rows 1 and 3

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct answer is:

> "**><**".

The sequence is that:

1. > The first and the second columns both have a two-characters field, so the third should also have one (under the "?" sign).
2. > As seen there, the middle field borrows characters from neighbouring fields.
3. > The "?" field borrows the 3rd and 4th characters from the top field of the third column.

This is why I think that the correct answer is

> "><".

(Don't get angry if it's not right. If possible, you could try again if available.)

P.S: If I wasn't right, you could try the "Try All" method and try every possible answer, starting with the 2-character ones.

Answer (score 0):

> don't over think this. top row shows <<(pointing left), middle row shows <>(pointing opposite), last row could then either be >< or >>. logic to me would say >>, as the middle row is pointing to the left and the right, to then complete the puzzle of point left, pointing left and right, and then pointing right.

i actually got this in a logical test i did, and was shown my results with this correct.