# Greater Than / Less Than Pattern

Tags: pattern

I can't solve this, maybe one of you can? My intuition is the answer is the >< but probably only because that appears in the surrounding squares.

[image: puzzle]

source: unknown but friend received it as warmup/practice question to skills test

Comment: If this is not the puzzle you've made, please put the source where did  you get this puzzle from

Comment: I'm almost certain I've seen this on PSE but I can't find the dupe...

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling? Where is this puzzle from, exactly? Puzzles without a source will be removed.

Comment: I've added the source to the question but I kind of object to the renaming of the question - I'm not sure the symbols take their mathematical significance

Comment: I don't think they do either, but this is a more specific title that can be searched for. If you have any better ideas for a title, you're free to change it.

Comment: @phenomist https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28407/logical-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> ><

I found different pattern from the OP:

> Remove a character which have same position and same direction from two symbols in the same row that contains 4 characters. It will give you two symbols with 3 characters. Choose the symbol with the last character is ">", remove it will give you the symbol with 2 characters which is another symbol in the same row
>
>  first row:
>  ><<> & >>>< remove the first will give you <<> & >><
>  choose <<>  remove the last character will give you **<<**
>
>  third row:
>  <>>< & ><<< remove the last will give you <>> & ><<
>  choose <>>  remove the last character will give you **<>**
>
>  so for the second row, because it's missing a symbol with 2 characters the only fit one is:
>  <><> & <<>< remove the first will give you ><> & <><
>  choose ><>  remove the last character will give you **><**

Answer (score 0):

One potential explanation:

> There are ten symbols in the first two columns. The first column has 7 < and 3 >. The second column has 6 < and 4 >. If we continue to decrease the < and increase the >, we would get 5 < and 5 > in the third column. There are already 3 < and 5 >, so with this logic the answer would be <<.